# Connecting to a JMS Queue using a file system based Initial Context

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

Using Websphere MQ Explorer, I have created a new `file system` based `initial context`for JMS. Using the new initial context, I have created a JMS queue to  connect to an existing queue (currently accessed using a non java based framework).

Within the application code, I can succesfully connect to the context, as follows:

```
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  "file:C://folder-name//");

try {
  val ctx = new InitialContext(properties)
```

Next, I create a QueueConnectionFactory:

```
val qcf = (ctx.lookup("com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueFactory")).asInstanceOf[QueueConnectionFactory]
```

However, this throws the following exception:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueFactory
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.getObjectFromBindings(RefFSContext.java:400)
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookupObject(RefFSContext.java:327)
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookup(RefFSContext.java:146)
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContext.lookup(FSContext.java:127)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
```

I used `com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueFactory` as the connection factory name, because in the `.bindings` file, there is the following line:

```
MY.QUEUE/FactoryName=com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueFactory
```

But that throws an exception.

Where would the correct connection factory name be defined?

Thanks

Comment: What MQ jar files are in the class path?

Comment: com.ibm.mqmqjms-7.5.0.2, com.ibm.mq,jmqi.7.5.0.2, com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar.7.0.1.4

Comment: Mix and matching MQ jars is not advisable (7.5.0.2 mixed with 7.0.1.4). Be sure to use jar files from the same revision-- e.g. 7.5.0.2 all the way.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - under the file based context (under JMS Administered Objects), a Connection Factory must be defined.